# How to get output of two integers being divided?

Tags: python, python-2.x, division

I have to divide two positive integers in Python 2 but I can't get the desired output.

like this:

```
>>> 2/6
```

The output should be

```
1/3
```

but it outputs zero like this:

```
0
```

Comment: It sounds like you want [Fractions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html)

Comment: Yes.. That's what I want. :-)

Comment: Oh. Thanks. How should I mark this as a duplicate?